# Flake8 не использует per-file-ignores из конфигурации

Tags: python, flake8

Проверяю код с помощью flake8, в конфигурации [wemake-python-styleguide](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-python-styleguide)

Запускаю просто `flake8` из корня проекта.  Вот фрагмент `setup.cfg`:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E800, A001
per-file-ignores =
# A001: ``copyright`` is hardcoded in Sphinx
# E800: Sphinx template needs commented out code;
    sites/docs/conf.py: A001, E800
```

С таким конфигом flake не находит ошибок.

Если строку c `ignore` закомментировать, то в файле `sites/docs/conf.py` flake найдёт оба вида ошибок, несмотря на явное исключение для файла.

Похоже, что flake учитывает переменную конфигурации `ignore`, но не учитывает `per-file-ignores`. Что я делаю не так, в чём ошибка?

Если что, вот [документация `per-file-ignores`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores).

Comment: Смею предположить что данная опция является не самостоятельной а уточняющей... т.е. работает только если игнорируемые ошибки для файла указзаны в `ignore`. Проверить можно оставив ignore как есть( с двумя ошибками) а в per-file-ignores оставить только одну

Comment: Наоборот получается: `ignore` действует на все файлы и без дополнительных опций.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков нашёл решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, что [per-file-ignores](https://github.com/snoack/flake8-per-file-ignores) — это отдельный модуль flake8, он не был установлен, а flake8 никак не обрабатывает неизвестные ему параметры конфигурации. Хотя мог бы предупреждение показывать.

Решение:

```
pipenv install flake8-per-file-ignores
```